# Magento2 The shipping information was unable to be saved: verify the input data and try again

Tags: magento2, checkout, magento2.3.2

While doing checkout I am seeing this issue?

I dint added any plugin for shipping. In log i am getting issue like **`StorePickupId`** does not have accessory method **`getStorePickupId`** in class Magento Checkout.

Please let me know the exact issue.

Answer (score 0):

This error happening because in the `estimate-shipping-methods` request exists field `store_pickup_id` inside the address, and corresponding interface `Magento\Quote\Api\Data\AddressInterface` has no accessory method for it. As a checkout works through Magento API all values which you pass must have getter and setter methods in the interface.

Here is example of that request with body:

> https://1001101010.com/default/rest/default/V1/guest-carts/MA6cowPQxDBpfRSSJmQrca36ytXV5g1L/estimate-shipping-methods

```
{
    "address": {
        "street": ["Mendeleeva str.", "30 112"],
        "city": "Minsk",
        "region_id": "517",
        "region": "Гродзенская вобласць",
        "country_id": "BY",
        "postcode": "123456",
        "firstname": "Siarhey",
        "lastname": "Uchukhlebau",
        "company": "",
        "telephone": "12345678"
    }
}
```

as you can see there no field `store_pickup_id`, but if you add it somehow, you get error in result (example from postman where is additional field `store_pickup_id` added manually in request body):

[image]

I'll recommend you to check:

1. request body
2. shipping address form
3. any third-party components and mixins

Comment: no any third party extension.I have checked in request body but nothing.Just I am getting this is in exception load.And I am not able to place order

Comment: @Maruti_magento2 just remove the StorePickupId poperty from request.

Comment: how is this possible..this is code generated..I am not passing anything..  now i solved this point with $this->doValidate($address, $cart->getCustomer()->getId() ? $cart->getCustomer()->getId() : null);  Now I able to redirect payment getway..

Comment: I wrote this in vendor/magento/module-quote/Model/QuoteAddressValidator.php..But now I am getting No such entity with customerId = vendor/magento/framework/Exception/NoSuchEntityException.php:50

Comment: My site is taking too much time to redirect, I have used  Ced commerce module.what will be the issue.I did lot more from doc. I am new to magento. Almost 45 sec take to load

Answer (score 0):

This is a magento issue that's still not solved yet. You can visit the following github issue (23980):
https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/23908

Answer (score 0):

solved it by setting the currency rate !! i dont know what is the relation between both of them but it worked fine
Stores -> Currency -> Currency Rates.

Answer (score 0):

For me it was a customisation I introduced. However, wasn't clear what was wrong. I just saw the error 'The shipping information was unable to be saved: verify the input data and try again'

In debug.log

```
[2022-07-05 10:32:47] main.CRITICAL: Notice: Array to string conversion in /vendor/magento/framework/DB/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php on line 3170 {"exception":"[object] (Exception(code: 0): Notice: Array to string conversion in /vendor/magento/framework/DB/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php on line 3170 at /vendor/magento/framework/App/ErrorHandler.php:61)"} []
```

In this file `vendor/magento/framework/DB/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php` I dropped some primitive logging

```
                [...]
                case 'longtext':
                error_log(__METHOD__ . "\n", 3, "/var/log/mysql.log");
                if (is_array($value)) {
                    error_log(print_r($value, true). "\n", 3, "/var/log/mysql.log");
                }
                $value  = (string)$value;
                [...]
```

That helped me catch object trying to be saved as string.

I used Magento \Magento\Framework\Serialize\SerializerInterface to serialize the object into string that I was using elsewhere.